# echo working in a very different way

Tags: bash

Here `PLUGIN=ABC`

```
$ echo "{\"PluginName\": \"${PLUGIN}\""
""PluginName": "ABC
$ echo "{\"PluginName\":${PLUGIN}\",\"Filename\":\"${VAR}\" , \"ErrorString\":"
","Filename":"ABC" , "ErrorString":eployerProps
```

However if I change above variable PLUGIN to any other string its working.

```
$ echo "{\"PluginName\":\"${PLUGINS}\",\"Filename\":\"${VAR}\" , \"ErrorString\":"
{"PluginName":"ABC","Filename":"ABC" , "ErrorString":
```

Not able to understand whats the reason. This is bash 4 however on other server its working fine.

Comment: The question input/output is a bit confusing.  Could you post the least code it takes to replicate this?

Comment: @Alex, I just want to print a string which is having some variables. But not able to do on a specific server only. After debugging I found that variable PLUGIN is the issue as highlighted above. But not sure why this is happening.  If I use PLUGIN than it is printing after ","

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the examples in your post though.  Are you saying that running the command `echo "{\"PluginName\": \"${PLUGIN}\""` gives you output `""PluginName": "ABC`?  What are you expecting the output to be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem. This is what my bash 4.4.23(1) prints:

```
$ PLUGIN=ABC
$ echo "{\"PluginName\": \"${PLUGIN}\""
{"PluginName": "ABC"
```

> However if I change above variable PLUGIN to any other string its working.

Have you noticed that your second command differs from the first one?

```
echo "{\"PluginName\":${PLUGIN}\",\"Filename\":\"${VAR}\" , \"ErrorString\":"
                      |       |
            different |        \  different
                      |         |
echo "{\"PluginName\":\"${PLUGINS}\",\"Filename\":\"${VAR}\" , \"ErrorString\":"
```

However, you could make your life a lot easier by using `printf`:

```
$ PLUGIN=ABC
$ VAR=XYZ
$ printf '{"PluginName": "%s"\n' "$PLUGIN"
{"PluginName": "ABC"
$ printf '{"PluginName":"%s","Filename":"%s","ErrorString":\n' "$PLUGIN" "$VAR"
{"PluginName":"ABC","Filename":"XYZ","ErrorString":
```

or even better for a general approach:

```
$ printf '{'; printf '"%s":"%s",' PluginName "$PLUGIN" Filename "$VAR"
{"PluginName":"ABC","Filename":"XYZ",
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here `PLUGIN=ABC`

No, that would not explain the output you're seeing. It's much more likely that `PLUGIN=$'ABC\r'` (i.e. A B C followed by a carriage return).

Carriage return moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line when printed to a terminal, which is why your output looks so confusing.

Try `echo "$PLUGIN" | cat -v` or `echo "$PLUGIN" | xxd` (or any other hex dump tool) to see what's actually in there.

> But not able to do on a specific server only.

If `PLUGIN` is the result of reading a line from a file, then this file is probably in Windows/DOS format on that server (with Carriage Return / Line Feed endings) instead of Unix format (Line Feed only).